Connectedness of intersection of two sets
Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathcal{R}^n$. Let $x_0\in \partial K$ (boundary of $K$). I want to show there exists a $\delta$ Such that $B_\delta(x_0)\cap K$ is connected. I don't even know if the statement is true. My thoughts are: Intersection of two convex sets is convex so it is connected. $B_\delta(x_0)$ is convex. But $K$ is not convex- so I am stuck. When I draw little diagrams the intersection is not always convex but if I make $\delta$ small enough, it always seems to be connected. If this is true how do I make this rigorous? If this is not true, can you provide a counter example?

@Pranay Why is your K compact? Your K is open, no?

Yes sorry, removed my comment.

@Pranay No problem. Thank you for trying to help.

Note that $x_0$ belongs to a connected component $C$ of $K$, and the connected components of $K$ are all disjoint, so there are disjoint open sets containing all of them. We then take the ball around $x_0$ to be contained within the open set containing $C$. So we can assume without loss of generality that $K$ is connected.

@Pranay Could you please elaborate? Suppose we assume $K$ is connected. How can I argue that $B_\delta(x_0)\cap K$ is connected?

If $K$ is connected, you can take $\delta$ large enough to enclose all of $K$. This can be done because $K$ is bounded. Then the intersection of $B_{\delta}(x_0)\cap K=K$ which is connected.

Actually, $K={0}\cup{2^{-n}:n\in \mathbb N}$ and $x_0=0$ is a counterexample.

I think you might want to ask that $K$ is connected... So you avoid easy counterexamples, like the one from @Pranay... Although of course this is not necessary (and for instance asking for a finite number of connected components should also do the job).

@ECL but if $K$ is connected, then the problem becomes trivial as John Douma explained in his comment.

@Pranay true...

This answer summarises what already discussed by several users in the comments and gives some further remarks.
The statement as you asked it lends itself to easy counterexamples, as pointed out by @Pranay. For instance, consider $K = \{0\}\cup\{1/n,\,n\geq 1\}$, with $x_0=0$.
You might want to add further assumptions to make the problem less trivial. For instance, you might ask that $K$ is itself connected. However, then there is a ball centred at $x_0$ that contains the whole $K$ and so the property is trivially true (as @John Douma pointed out in their comment).
Now, I suspect that what you are actually interested in is if it is possible to get "small" open balls with a connected intersection with $K$. In this sense, an alternative related question is if when $K$ is compact and connected, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $\delta'\in(0,\delta)$ the intersection $K\cap B_{\delta'}(x_0)$ is connected. As a side remark, note that this is equivalent to ask that $K$ is locally connected. However, in general a compact and connected subset of $\mathbb R^n$ does not have to be locally connected. For instance, consider the classical comb example in $\mathbb R^2$. This is defined as follows. Let $S[P, Q]$ denote the segment connecting the point $P$ to the point $Q$ in $\mathbb R^2$. Then let
$$K = S[(0,0), (0,1)] \cup  S[(0,0), (1,0)] \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S[(0, 1/n),(1, 1/n)]\,.$$
This is a compact and connected set, but taking $x_0 = (1,0)$ you can easily check that there is no ball with radius $\delta<1$ that has a connected intersection with $K$.
Finally, note that this last counterexample also shows that the following statement is not true: "If $K$ is compact and has finitely many connected components, then for each $x_0\in K$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $B_\delta(x_0) \cap K$ is connected.". Indeed, take as $K$ the comb defined earlier plus the point $(1, 3/4)$. Again, let $x_0 = (1,0)$. Then, any ball with radius at least $1$ contains $(1, 3/4)$, and so has a non-connected intersection with $K$. But we also know that no ball with a radius smaller than $1$ has a connected intersection with the comb.

Thank you so much for the comprehensive answer. Perhaps I did not impose enough conditions on $K$. The kind of $K$ I'm interested in is the set of all points that are less than or equal to the distance $r$ away from a compact set. Should I write it up as a new question?

Yes I think you should post a different question for that, trying to formulate precisely what you need.

From your answer, the statement would be true if $K$ is locally connected?

The statement is not true if you don't consider the trivial ball that contains all $K$ in the case in which $K$ is connected.
Consider the set  $\ Y=\left\{\left(x, \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) \  \vert \ x>0\right\}$ on the plane $\ \mathbb{R}^2$ with the euclidean topology.
Now let be $\ K=\text{cl}(Y)\cap[-1,1]^2$,
where $\ $cl$(Y)=Y\cup\{(0,y)\  \vert -1\leq y\leq1\}$ is the closure of $\ Y$.
The origin is in the boundary of $K$ (which is compact because it's bounded and closed) but if you take any open ball of the origin $B$, as small as you want, then $B\cap K$ is not connected since there are infinitely many connected components given by the graph of the function $\ \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.

But $B_\delta(0)\cap K$ is connected if $\delta>\sqrt 2$, so this is not a counterexample.

Yes, you're right @TonyK, I completely didn't consider the trivial case since it was indeed trivial for me.
